# Will IIS recycle application pool if web application has pending long-running request?

Tags: c#, iis, long-polling, application-pool

**Intro**

I am developing a web application using ASP.NET MVC 3, C#, targeting IIS 7.0+. We have a number of long-running async requests (utilizing AsyncController/Async action features). I also use HttpRuntime.Cache quite often (and in some non-standard way which doesn't really matter here).

**Question**

Can IIS application pool be suddenly recycled if there are active long-running requests present? I want to prevent that behavior if possible as I don't want to lose data from cache.

Do I really need to use some persistent storage (i.e. Database) to overcome possible issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally IIS won't recycle an application which has pending requests for it due to period of inactivity. But IIS could recycle your application if you hit memory or CPU tresholds. But this is something that you could configure in your IIS management console.

Comment: Thanks! A follow-up question: is there a way to prevent such recycles on hitting load thresholds? Or at least to track them via some event handling so I can preliminary save all the data to persistent storage and restore them after recycle?

Comment: Yes, I think you could disable those recycles in the IIS management console in the advanced properties of your Application Pool configuration.

Answer (score 1):

When a recycle is triggered there is a "shutdown time limit" that defaults to 90 seconds.  That's how long processes have to finish before they will be shutdown forcibly.  This is configurable through IIS, you likely want to increase this to a large value in addition to removing non-desired recycle triggers (memory, CPU, time, schedule, requests, etc.)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but in my case that's not enough, I have requests running for several hours. I'm server owner and always will be (and I'm sure in my code quality), so I've just disabled periodic recycling.